# HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection: expected: PluralAttributeImpl$SetAttributeImpl; encountered: SingularAttribute

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpamodelgen

I recently updated my Spring boot project from 1.5.6 to 2.0.2 and having now a problem with one of my entites and their metamodel generation.
The problem occurs with a mapping of Set of Enums which was working before i switched to 2.0.2.

While starting the webapp it shows me the following error in my log:

```
HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : xxx.TestEntity_#testEnums; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.PluralAttributeImpl$SetAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute
```

**The entity and its mapping:**

```
public class TestEntity extends AbstractEntity {

   ...

   @JsonIgnore
   @ElementCollection(targetClass = TestEnum.class)
   @Convert(converter = TestEnumConverter.class)
   @CollectionTable(name = "engine_test_enum", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_entity_id"))
   private Set<TestEnum> testEnums = new HashSet<>();

   ...
}
```

**The Enum**

```
public enum TestEnum implements CodeEnum, AliasEnum {

   TEST1(1, "ALIAS1"),
   TEST2(2, "ALIAS2"),
   // ... and so on ...
   ;

   private Integer code;
   private String alias;

   private TestEnum(Integer code, String alias) {
       this.code = code;
       this.alias = alias;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer getCode() {
       return code;
   }

   @Override
   public String getAlias() {
       return alias;
   }
}
```

**Converter class**

```
@Converter
public class TestEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<TestEnum, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(TestEnum testEnum) {
        return TestEnum == null ? null : testEnum.getCode();
    }

    @Override
    public TestEnum convertToEntityAttribute(Integer code) {
        return EnumUtils.fromCode(TestEnum.class, code);
    }

}
```

**Metamodel generated class**

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(TestEntity.class)
public abstract class TestEntity_ extends xxx.AbstractEntity_ {

    ...

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<TestEntity, TestEnum> testEnum;

    ...
}
```

**My dependencies:**

- all spring boot projects: 2.0.2.RELEASE
- hibernate-core & hibernate-jpamodelgen: 5.2.17.Final
- some more libs which are needed for the project

Does anybody know the reason for this behavior? 
First i thought it was just a problem cleaning the workspace (using eclipse). But regenerating the metamodel classes seem to be ok according to their timestamps. 
As we can see the generated class contains indeed a SingularAttribute...but what am i doing wrong that this is not mapped as:

```
SetAttribute<TestEntity, TestEnum> testEnums;
```

?

Comment: You're affected by https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11803

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) here :

> The Convert annotation should not be used to specify conversion of the
>   following: Id attributes, version attributes, relationship attributes,
>   and attributes explicitly denoted as Enumerated or Temporal.

So instead of an `Enum`, you can use an embeddable class and use a dot (".") notation in the `attributeName` element to indicate an attribute within an embedded attribute, which in this case will be your embedded class.